# Trigger onblur event on click of enter keypress in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, focus

I have an input text field . When a user inputs any text and clicks enter button I need to activate the blur event to remove the focus and also to validate the textinput .

```
<input type="text" 
    style={{marginTop:'20%', marginLeft:'40%'}} 
    value={value} 
    onFocus={onFocus}
    onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
    onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `refs` and `this.inputRef.current.blur()`.This is working solution.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }
  keypressHandler = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.setState({ value: this.inputRef.current.value });
      this.inputRef.current.blur();
      this.inputRef.current.value = "";
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <label>Enter Text</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={this.inputRef}
          onKeyPress={event => this.keypressHandler(event)}
        />
        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: From the docs `Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.` and `Don’t Overuse Refs` -https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 26):

Instead of `onKeyPress`, use `onKeyDown` which detects `keyCode` events.

```
<input type="text"
    style={{marginTop:'20%', marginLeft:'40%'}} 
    value={value} 
    onFocus={onFocus} 
    onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
    onKeyDown={(e) => this.handleKeyPress(event)}
/>
```

And the function will be like,

```
handleKeyPress(e){
   if(e.keyCode === 13){
     e.target.blur(); 
     //Write you validation logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: MDN docs say [KeyboardEvent.KeyCode is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). "Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; [...] Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time." And "You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some time. Instead, you should use [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), if it's implemented [...] be careful to make sure you use one which is supported on all target browsers."

Comment: There is also [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) which is probably a better choice for just detecting that the user has pressed `Enter`.

Comment: Note that this correctly triggers the `blur` event but it removes certain default behaviour of the input that used to be triggered by the `Enter` key (such as submitting a form, automatically moving to the next field in the form, etc).

Answer (score 1):

One-liner would be:

```
<input
...
onKeyDown={(e) => e.key === "Escape" && e.target.blur()}    
/>
```