# Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'Input'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, native-base

I am using the `useRef` hook to pass a `ref` property into my custom FieldInput component. This is then used for the validation of my form.

```
const fieldRef = useRef();
...
    const handleSubmitForm = (
    values: FormValues,
    helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>,
  ) => {
 ....
    fieldRef.current.blur();
    helpers.resetForm();
  };
```

However, I get an error on fieldRef.current that `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`. In order to fix that, I made these changes:

```
const fieldRef = useRef<Input>(null);
...
fieldRef.current?.blur();
```

However, I still get an error that `Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'Input'.`. Here, `Input` is imported from native-base. Due to this, I get type errors/warnings when I submit the form. `An unhandled error was caught from submitForm()`
How can I get rid of these errors?

The full scenario is replicated here in a **codesandbox**: https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/jealous-beef-jerky-fix

Comment: I was able to click Search just fine. What error on submission are you referring to?

Comment: `.blur()` is a jQuery call. Are you using jQuery library? If not you need to bind an event or trigger the `onBlur` event.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217115/trigger-onblur-event-on-click-of-enter-keypress-in-react-js/56217464

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all, in your `FieldInput` component, you passed those event handlers to `Input` like this : `<Input onCahnge={callback()}/>` , instead of doing it like this : `<Input onChange={()=>callback()}/>` . Instead of passing your callbacks, you called them and passed in their result as the event handlers. This caused an error in your component.

After fixing that and getting type hints working, `blur` was still signaled by the editor as missing from type `Input`. After looking over the docs, and trying to console log the ref element, it seems like there is actually no `blur` method exposed. `TextField` from `react-native` has it exposed, but is not forwarded to `native-base` `Input`

Comment: {()=>callback()} If I change it to this, I can no longer type in the input field properly as the text keeps getting deleted. I checked this problem on a simulator and real device, not sure if the problem exists in web mode or not. Could you maybe edit the sandbox and show if it doesn't give you the error?

Comment: 1. Yes, you can't get rid of that error.
2. With typescript and react native, `handleChange()` is not an option. You should use the `setFieldValue()` instead

Comment: Instead of ```useRef<Input>(null)```, if I change it to ```useRef<any>``` the inline error is removed. However, I still need a workaround for the warning ```TypeError: _fieldRef$current.blur is not a function```that I get on submitting the form (for the current codesansbox)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667170/touched-property-not-being-reset this was my original issue. To overcome this, I tried using useRef but this is also giving me warnings. Is there another way to fix it without using useRef? 2. Where are you suggesting me to use setFieldValue() exactly? 3. {()=>callback()} If I change it to this, I can no longer type in the input field properly as the text keeps getting deleted.

Comment: Well there is no workaround for the error. The error tells you that there is no `blur` function on that element.

Comment: Check out this code repo regarding that callback fix: https://snack.expo.io/@adi_random/fix

Comment: I couldn't run your expo probably because there's App.tsx and App.js both and I can't delete one myself. Nevertheless, I tried the setField option in my app and it didn't work. I could no longer type in my field.